# “this” in function parameter in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, this, asp.net-web-api

I am developing web api, we have created HtmlLHelper class, and I see declarations that look like:

```
public static string GetCountryDomain(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Area area)
    {
        //body
    }
```

In my controller I want to call above function. It expects 2 parameters.

```
HtmlHelper.GetCountryDomain(area_id);
```

can someone explain what first parameter I need to pass in order to call above function?

Answer (score 1):

`this` keyword marks an extension method. There are two ways of calling it:

- You can call it as if it were an instance method on `HtmlHelper`, or
- You can call it like a normal `static` method passing two parameters.

The first way is more common (after all, that's the point of making the method an extension)

```
// Prepare the parameters
HtmlHelper helper = ...
Area area = ...
// Call the function
string countryDomain = helper.GetCountryDomain(area);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension method. You can call it normally, in which case you need to pass an instance of System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper and an int to the static method. Since it is a static method, you need to specify the class as well:

```
Area area = HtmlHelperExtensions.GetAreaById(htmlHelper, i);
```

But extension methods can also be called as if they were an instance method of the first parameter:

```
Area area = htmlHelper.GetAreaById(i);
```

This is just syntactic sugar; what happens in reality is the first call. For more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: Hi. I have slightly modified my function. Please have a look.

Comment: This guy always explains things very well: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkghGK4bdtg&index=2&list=PL90AF0EFFEF782D27

Answer (score 0):

`GetAreaById` is an extension method. So the first parameter is already the `HtmlHelper`.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote an extension method. The syntax is intended to mimic adding method to an existing class. You will pass an `HtmlHelper` object as the first parameter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

This particular type of helper classes is available in your view.

```
You can use the HtmlHelper class in a view by using the built-in 
Html property of the view. For example, calling @Html.ValidationSummary()
renders a summary of validation messages.
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`GetAreaById` is an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). You can think of it as a method that is "attached" to an instance of a specific type but is not defined within the definition of that type.

Also, being a static method, it may be used in two ways:

As an instance method of the type preceded by `this` keyword

```
var helper = new System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper();
var area = helper.GetAreaById(id);
```

As a static method by passing the instance as a parameter:

```
var helper = new System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper();
var area = ClassWhereMethodIsDefined.GetAreaById(helper, id);
```